# How to caluclate conditional probability over 2 confidence intervals after a softmax on a classifier prediction?

Tags: confidence-interval, conditional-probability

Given 2 confidence intervals from 2 different models with 3 classes each:

ci1 = [0.2, 0.4, 0.4]

ci2 = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]

Where each score corresponds to a class.
How to find the conditional probablity of a class ?

Here you can assume that the confidence interval is the output of a classifier model and each number is the confidence of a class (considering a 3 class classifier) after a softmax. The goal to accomplish is to have a final prediction that takes into consideration results of both these models

Formula states `P(B|A) = P(A and B) / P(A)`

But wouldn't that be just P(B) in this case?

Comment: You're likely looking for confidence regions, in which case you need to account for the covariance between whatever statistics those confidence intervals are based on.

Comment: What does "ci2 = [0.1, 0.5, 0.3]" mean with three numbers rather than the two ends of an interval?

Comment: (1) In what sense is a vector of *three* values a "confidence interval"?? I thought perhaps one vector would be lower limits and the other would be upper limits, but they are too inconsistent for that interpretation. (2) To find a conditional probability of a class, you would have to use Bayes' Theorem and assume some prior class distribution.  But then you wouldn't be working with confidence intervals: you would use Bayesian credible intervals.  There's a fundamental disconnect here.  Could you therefore clarify what it is you are really working with and what you really need to accomplish?

Comment: Here you can assume that the confidence interval is the output of a classifier model and each number is the confidence of a class (considering a 3 class classifier) after a softmax. The goal to accomplish is to have a final prediction that takes into consideration results of both these models